# Porque el boton enviar no altera las modificaciones a la base de datos?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Tengo un incoveniente en mi sistema el boton enviar no altera los datos en la funcion edit y no sé el porque, podrian darme una mano por favor este es mi controlador.

funcion edit

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $people = people::where('id','=',$id)->get()->first();
    $companies = company::get();
    return view('people.edit',compact('people', 'companies'));
}
```

Funcion update

```
public function update(Request $request, people $people, company $companies)
{
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'people_type' => 'required',
            'legal' => 'required'
        ]);
        
        $people->update($request->all());
        
       
        return redirect()->route('people.index')
        ->with('Exito','Persona actualizado
         con exito');
        }
}
```

Comment: Tuve un problema similar, ,muchas veces el error esta en las variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esta modificando el campo sin consulta el id

```
<?php
use App\people;
...
...    
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //$id = $request->id; otra forma de obtener el id 
        $people = people::findOrFail($id);
        $data = $request->all();
        $people->update($data);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Datos actualizado');
    
    }
```

además tiene que añadir los campos de la tabla en el modelo

En el archivo /app/people.php deber añadir los nombre de los campos de la tabla en $fillable, si no lo declara no lo modifica

```
    namespace App;
    class people extends Model  {
    
    protected $table = 'people';
    protected $fillable = [
      'id',
      'name',
      'last_name',
      ...
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos me sirvio mucho... el Modelo estaba correcto lo que me faltaba era el id. Muchas Gracias...